# macro for creating matrix rows for Node optimization

Tags: excel, row, traveling-salesman

I am currently working on a traveling sales person problem in Excel. For this I need to generate two rows parallel to each other ( Row1 for row Row2 for column) and use INDEX MATCH MATCH to look up the distances between nodes and solve using solver in order to get the best sequence to minimize distance.

For example I have row0 of four nodes named [1][2][3][4].

- Distance matrix
- __[1][2][3][4]
- [1] 0,  4,  5, 7
- [2] 4,  0,  6,  2
- [3] 5,  6,  0,  1
- [4] 7,  2,  1,  0

It must take row 0 and using a macro to develop the following 2 rows

- Row 1  [1][1][1][2][2][3]
- Row 2  [2][3][4][3][4][4]

Then I can use the Index Match Match to automatically bring all the distances below in a third row:

- Row 1  [1][1][1][2][2][3]
- Row 2  [2][3][4][3][4][4]
- Row 3    4,  5,  7,  6,  2,  1

Please I need help developing the macro to create row 1 an row 2. This should be able to account for any amount of nodes and not just the 4 listed in the example.

Comment: I don't think anyone is just going to write the code for you.  You will do better to post code you have written and then ask about what is not working.

Comment: The node names isn't necessarily ascending meaning the names in row0 might be [9][2][3][5][1][11]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for row 2. Sorry if it seems like a basic question but I am a noob at VBA and hoping to get better. Ill post when I have the answer for the next row.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
k = 5
i = 0
j = 0
rwar = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(13, 5).Value
For i = 3 To rwar + 1
rwar = rwar - 1
    For j = 1 To rwar
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(16, k) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value
    k = k + 1
    Next j

Next i


'
End Sub
```